# What does the definition of BigDecimal mean?

Tags: java, math

The first paragraph of the javadoc for BigDecimal says:

> Immutable, arbitrary-precision signed decimal numbers.
>     A BigDecimal consists of an arbitrary precision integer
>     unscaled value and a 32-bit integer scale. If zero or positive,
>     the scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal
>     point. If negative, the unscaled value of the number is
>     multiplied by ten to the power of the negation of the scale.
>     The value of the number represented by the BigDecimal
>     is therefore (unscaledValue × 10-scale)

Can someone explain what this means, especially the bit starting 'If negative', but preferably all of it? I think that 'scale' means the numbers after the decimal point, but does that mean the 'unscaled' is the rest of it?

Comment: Do you know what `float` and/or `double` are? I mean in a way they are stored.

Comment: No. I know it's not good to use them for calculations where precision is important, but I don't know how they are stored internally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scale means the power of ten by which the magnitude of the number is multiplied. The power could be positive or negative. When the power is negative k, the corresponding negative power of ten is a fraction with 1 in the numerator and the denominator is 10<sup>k</sup>. To put this simply, positive scale k means multiplying by 10 k times; negative scale of -k means dividing by 10 k times.

Here are some examples:

```
magnitude scale    value
--------- ----- -------------
1.2345678   -3   0.0012345678
1.2345678   -2   0.012345678
1.2345678   -1   0.12345678
1.2345678    0   1.2345678
1.2345678    1   12.345678
1.2345678    2   123.45678
1.2345678    3   1234.5678
```

**Note :** The dot in the magnitude above is *implied*. `BigDecimal` stores the magnitude of the number as an arbitrarily large integer.

Comment: Ah.. so 'scaling' is an operation, and BigDecimal stores its values as integers and then scales them to represent the decimals? So the 'unscaled' value is the value before scaling, and the 'scale' means the size of the scaling. I think I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: @user384842 `BigDecimal` stores the two operands (the magnitude and the scale) separately. These two values together represent the actual value of `BigDecimal`. This representation lets `BigDecimal` avoid storing lots and lots of leading and/or trailing zeros for numbers that are really big or the numbers that are really small.

Comment: Great answer, +1. But I bet BigDecimal doesn't store the magnitude in a floating point number(?). If it stores it as an (arbitrarily large) integer, your example table is slightly misleading...